# Access forbidden contact your app developer

Tags: rpc

This code used to work fine to look up my SOL balance in my wallet:

```
  const loadBalances = async (walletKey: string) => {
    console.log('looking up balances for: ', walletKey);
    let connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');
    connection.getBalance(new PublicKey(walletKey)).then(function (value) {
      setSol(Math.floor(value / 10000000) / 100);
    })
  }
```

But now it's failing:

```
POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/
[HTTP/2 403 Forbidden 45ms]

Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to get balance of account 7KQWkLzkCqvncL*********hJUXChukr5EZ:
Error: 403 Forbidden:  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403,
"message":"Access forbidden, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com."},
"id": "587199fc-731b-4b1a-a151-2257c543dc21" }
```

This code is running in my react app on a browser.

I tried some different endpoints and that doesn't work either.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the public RPC at https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com, there are very strict rate limits as outlined here.

Getting 403 means that you were banned for some abuse. Recommend getting another free RPC elsewhere. You can find a list of RPCs here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

This doesnt work from the frontend anymore (react app).

You need to run this code from the backend (server).